# Cannot get colorchooser to change line color

Tags: java, swing, drawing, panel, jcolorchooser

Been trying for over 6 hours now and I keep finding the same answers from everyone regarding the changing of a background color within a JPanel drawing frame. The problem is I don't want/need to touch the background color, its the line color on this mouse draw application I can't seem to get working at all.

Here is what I have so far, it's not done. I'm suppose to be putting a combo box in for line thickness selection and an erase function, but I can't get past this. HELP!

```
    JButton jButton_SetColour.setBounds(721, 104, 89, 23);
    frame_SetColour = new JButton("Colour");
    jButton.getContentPane().add(jButton_SetColour);
    jButton_SetColour.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
          Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,"Pick Your Colour", frame.getForeground());   
                if (color != null)frame.getContentPane();
                JColorChooser.setColor());
                }

                }
```

Comment: your code snippet doesn't make sense (why would you set the color of the _chooser_ if you want to change the "pen color" on a drawing tool ?) Best read the relevant chapter of your textbook again. And while you are at it: a) please learn java naming conventions and stick to them b) use self-explaining names (vs. confusing yourself and others with calling a frame a jbutton...)

Comment: we weren't given a text book for this class, the teacher is "unconventional" or bad, or whatever you want to classify his lack of information as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like i said, really new at this so it was perserverance and attention, but i managed to get it running.

```
    JButton jButton_sete = new JButton("Set Choice");
    jButton_sete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    drawColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Set Choice",choice);
        if (choice != null) {
            g2dImg.setPaint(choice);
    });
```

i needed to understand how to associate the actionlistener to the choice variable through jColorChooser, rookie error.